# Scrapy use other variables of item in item processor

Tags: python, scrapy

I am requesting adress information for a webservice to crosscheck whether the adres that I already have is in the same format as the webservice I am requesting from.

For this I have the following item with the following input_processor:

```
class AdresItem(scrapy.Item):

    postal_code = scrapy.Field()
    house_number = scrapy.Field()
    addition = scrapy.Field()
    scraped_addition = scrapy.Field(
                                 input_processor = MapCompose(MyFunction),
                                 output_processor = TakeFirst()
                              )


def MyFunction(scraped_addition):
    if scraped_addition == addition
        return scraped_addition
    else:
        return None
```

ofcourse I can't access the original addition this way. What would be a good way to go about using another variable of the item in the input processor?

Comment: Do you want to filter duplicate items?

Comment: No, the goal is to find the correct houseAddition format. For example, for an adress I have an addition in the format of F28. The server which I am trying to scrape requires the addition in the format of F-28. To find the correct formatting I can first request all additions for a given postal code and house number, from all given additions (i.e. ````['F-26','F-28,'F-30']````) I want to match my F28 with F-28 and choose F-28 as my new addition. I can come up with workarounds which are very messy, but I am looking for a clean solution using the itemloaders and processors of scrapy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the variable through [item context](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#item-loader-context) and load the variable in the function.

Example:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose


def MyFunction(scraped_addition, loader_context):
    addition = loader_context.get('addition')
    if scraped_addition == addition:
        return scraped_addition
    else:
        return None


class ExampleItem(scrapy.Item):
    scraped_addition = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(MyFunction))


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'exampleSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    def parse(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=ExampleItem(), response=response)
        l.context['addition'] = 'Long-sleeved Jersey Top'
        l.add_xpath('scraped_addition', '//h3/text()')
        yield l.load_item()
```